# Android VpnService route exclusion on API prior to 33

Tags: java, android, networking, android-vpn-service

I have an android app which uses VpnService API to establish a connection to a proxy. My intention is to let DNS queries bypass the proxy (because it can only tunnel TCP, and not UDP, which is used by DNS) and route the rest of the device traffic through it. On SDK 33+ I can do it like this:

```
Builder builder = new VpnService.Builder();
            ParcelFileDescriptor vpnInterface = builder
                    .setMtu(1500)
                    .addAddress("26.26.26.1", 24)
                    .addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0)
                    .excludeRoute(new IpPrefix(InetAddress.getByName("8.8.8.8"), 32))
                    .addDnsServer("8.8.8.8")
                    .establish();
```

But the `excludeRoute` method does not seem to exist on API 32 and lower. Is the only option to add routes like this:
`1.0.0.0/8,  2.0.0.0/8,  3.0.0.0/8,  4.0.0.0/6,  8.0.0.0/13 8.8.0.0/16 8.8.8.0...8.8.8.8/32`
or are there more elegant methods?